# is it possible 'PHP Spreadsheet' upper 10 value appear with yellow color

Tags: phpspreadsheet

Here is my code which produced simple bar chart based on values. Now I want to colorize if value is more than 10.

I think the problem is dataSeriesValue it only produce one time graph based one type of dataseries. Any possible way to use twice? such as if the value is more than 10 than it color yellow, below 10 is green, below 1 is red

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Chart;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\DataSeries;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\DataSeriesValues;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Legend;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\PlotArea;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Title;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(30);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(30);

$worksheet->setCellValue('A1','Bazar Name');
$worksheet->setCellValue('B1','Number of Shops');

$worksheet->fromArray([
    [''],
    ['Bazar Name 1', 9],
    ['Bazar Name 2', 16],
    ['Bazar Name 3', 7],
]);



$dataSeriesLabels = [
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, '', null, 1), // 2010
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, '', null, 1), // 2011
];

$xAxisTickValues = [
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A$4', null, 1), //  Q1 to Q4
];

$dataSeriesValues = [    
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, '(Worksheet!$B$2,Worksheet!$B$3,Worksheet!$B$4)', null, 4),
];

//Build the dataseries
$series = new DataSeries(
    DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART, // plotType
    DataSeries::GROUPING_CLUSTERED, // plotGrouping
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues) - 1), // plotOrder
    $dataSeriesLabels, // plotLabel
    $xAxisTickValues, // plotCategory
    $dataSeriesValues        // plotValues
);

$plotArea = new PlotArea(null, [$series]);
$legend = new Legend(Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, null, false);

$title = new Title('Test Bar Chart');
$yAxisLabel = new Title('Nogot Report');

//  Create the chart
$chart = new Chart(
    'chart1', // name
    $title, // title
    $legend, // legend
    $plotArea, // plotArea
    true, // plotVisibleOnly
    0, // displayBlanksAs
    null, // xAxisLabel
    $yAxisLabel  // yAxisLabel
);

$chart->setTopLeftPosition('A7');
$chart->setBottomRightPosition('H20');

$worksheet->addChart($chart);

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);**strong text**
$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
//$writer->save('test.xlsx');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xlsx"');
$writer->save("php://output");
```